# Unable to run flutter application show MissingPluginException

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using `AWS appsync` in my flutter project and when I do **Pug Get** and run the application get this error

```
E/flutter (19300): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAndroidDeviceInfo on channel plugins.flutter.io/device_info)
 
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
E/flutter (19300): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAndroidDeviceInfo on channel plugins.flutter.io/device_info)
E/flutter (19300): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:319:7)
```

Getting error in flutter project Build.
The same issue come with `path_provider, packageinfo`

Answer (score 0):

You need to full restart your application whenever you add new package or assets in your application. It will not work with hot reload and hot restart.

Comment: assets and packages that don't access native code doesn't need to recompile, hot restart will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Do these thing, and it will work. Make sure, you quit the app, by pressing `q` in your terminal. Follow these steps after this `one by one` in your project file path terminal.

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```

**OR**

```
flutter clean && flutter run
```

> `&&` helps to run multiple commands one by one.

What `flutter clean` does is, it removed the pre-cached data used in your app, including the packages data. It deletes the file, `dart_tool` and `build` which stores your data.

Then, it runs your flutter application. It is always advisable to do `flutter clean` before you do `flutter run`. It makes the runnable project light.